# Setting a salt for password_hash()

Tags: php, salt, owncloud, php-password-hash

I'm creating a mass user import script in PHP for `owncloud`. I read the users from a CSV file, then I'll add them to the `owncloud database`. I'm having an issue with the passwords though. To my knowledge, owncloud uses `password_hash()` with `BCRYPT`. I have the `passwordsalt`, but I'm not sure how to use that salt with `password_hash()`.

Any help there guys?

Comment: Bcrypt generates its own salt - you don't need to add one. You don't need to store one either as the salt bcrypt generates is part of the resulting bcrypt hash.

Comment: This is simple and doesn't even deserve to be an answer. Simply append the salt somewhere to the password you're hashing. At the beginning, at the end, or both, or whatever. The reason for this practice is that people can form dictionaries of hashes to password, which makes it easy to find common passwords in stolen databases. SALT helps, since all the passwords become unique, even if it's `qwerty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use salt in the option array like this

```
password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 7, "salt" => "thisisyoursalt"));
```

But using your own salt is not a good idea. Let `password_hash()` create a salt for your password. `password_hash()` will create different salt for every password. It will increase your password security strength.

Comment: Should perhaps include a note on why it's a bad idea to use your own salt ^^

Comment: owncloud seems to have a different way of doing it then. I get different passwords using their salt, but I understand why it's not a good idea to use a predetermined salt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked your answer as correct, as it answers my questions, just doesn't quite meet my requirements. I did manage to get it working though, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the hashes are produced by `password_hash()` or `crypt()`, then the salt is included in the resulting hash value. To check a password against this hash, you can use the function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), this function extracts the salt and other parameters automatically.

```
// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```